# Why is my crontab task (python script) not executing periodically?

Tags: scripts, python, cron, django

I need to  to execute a python script for periodically for my django project.So I'm using django_crontab.

This is what `crontab -e` has

```
*/1 * * * * /home/myvenv/bin/python /home/user/myproj/manage.py crontab run b74d4d1f47748498b81b5bcf863684c3 >> /home/user/myproj/myapp/file.log
```

The python script should print out 'Hello' to file.log every 1 minute.

```
def cronSendEmail():
    print("Hello")
    return True
```

The log at /var/log/syslog

```
Jan  3 22:35:01 me CRON[24607]: (myuser) CMD (/home/myvenv/bin/python /home/user/myproj/manage.py crontab run b74d4d1f47748498b81b5bcf863684c3 >> /home/user/myproj/file.log
Jan  3 22:35:02 me CRON[24606]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

This is being logged every minute, but 'Hello' is not printed. file.log is empty. Why is "Hello" not being printed? Is No MTA installed, discarding output, the key problem?

EDIT: This is django project and I'm creating the task via django-crontab in settings.py

```
CRONJOBS = [ ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cronSendEmail', '>> /home/user/myproj/file.log') ]
```

Comment: Is that your *complete* python script? you don't appear to actually *call* the `cronSendEmail()` function

Comment: I'm calling it. This is actually a django project and I'm calling it via django-crontab in settings.py: 

    `CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cronSendEmail', '>> /home/user/myproj/file.log')
]`

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: "This is being logged every minute" clearly indicated that the cron job  IS running. The task is executing...it's just failing with an error message every time. Look up how to redirect STDERR to your log so you can read the error message.

Comment: Thanks so much for the STDERR advice! I had messed up the path to the python function. It works now.